# SQL Select exclusive ids comparing master list with two sub lists

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, join, outer-join

I need help with an SQL query. I have a "Master list table (X and Y categories)". I have to compare the above list with two Sub list tables - "List X" and "List Y"

Tables:

```
*MasterList*              
ID Cat Status           
101 X  Ready            
102 X  Ready            
103 Y  Dispatched Y     
104 X  Dispatched Y     
105 Y  Dispatched       
106 X  Ready
107 X  Dispatched Y
108 Y  Ready Y
109 X  Dispatched
110 Y  Dispatched
111 X  Ready Y
112 X  Dispatched
113 X  Dispatched Y

*ListX* 
ID    
101   
102   
106
109
112

*ListY*
ID
105
110
```

I am trying to create a query which outputs:

1. Cat-X IDs which are not available in List-X
2. Cat-Y IDs which are not available in List-Y

Output

```
ID  Cat Status
103  Y  Dispatched
104  X  Dispatched
107  X  Dispatched
108  Y  Ready
111  X  Ready
113  X  Dispatched
```

Thanks,

Ravi.

Comment: Oracle or mysql? Also, please post some sample data (formatted text), needed result and what you tried so far

Comment: Thanks Strawberry, I am trying to do the same :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in several ways, for instance like here:

```
select * 
  from master_list 
  where (cat = 'X' and id not in (select id from listx))
     or (cat = 'Y' and id not in (select id from listy))
```

Also try `not exists` and simple joins.

---

Test data in Oracle and output:

```
create table master_list (id int, cat varchar2(1), status varchar2(15));
insert into master_list values (101, 'X', 'Ready');
insert into master_list values (102, 'X', 'Ready');
insert into master_list values (103, 'Y', 'Dispatched');
insert into master_list values (104, 'X', 'Dispatched');
insert into master_list values (105, 'Y', 'Dispatched');
insert into master_list values (106, 'X', 'Ready');
insert into master_list values (107, 'X', 'Dispatched');
insert into master_list values (108, 'Y', 'Ready');
insert into master_list values (109, 'X', 'Dispatched');
insert into master_list values (110, 'Y', 'Dispatched');
insert into master_list values (111, 'X', 'Ready');
insert into master_list values (112, 'X', 'Dispatched');
insert into master_list values (113, 'X', 'Dispatched');

create table listx as (select column_value id 
                         from table(sys.odcinumberlist(101, 102, 106, 109, 112)));
create table listy as (select column_value id 
                         from table(sys.odcinumberlist(105, 110)));

  ID CAT STATUS
---- --- ---------------
103 Y   Dispatched
104 X   Dispatched
107 X   Dispatched
108 Y   Ready
111 X   Ready
113 X   Dispatched
```

Comment: Ponder, this worked perfect for me. May I use the same even if the comparison ID is a String?

Comment: Yes. I don't think that type of column should matter unless they are the same in all tables. It's always good to put such informations in main question.

Comment: Thanks Ponder. I tried that as well. Just to confirm so that I might be able to use it in future :)

Comment: Glad I could help :-) If this closes the question please mark one of our answers as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OR in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT ID, CAT, STATUS 
  FROM MASTERLIST M
 WHERE (M.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM LISTX) AND CAT = 'X')
    OR (M.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM LISTY) AND CAT = 'Y');
```

Other alternative would be to separate the rules in two querys and combine then with an UNION ALL:

```
SELECT ID, CAT, STATUS 
  FROM MASTERLIST M
 WHERE M.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM LISTX) AND CAT = 'X'
 UNION ALL
SELECT ID, CAT, STATUS 
  FROM MASTERLIST M
 WHERE M.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM LISTY) AND CAT = 'Y';
```

Both techniques will lead to the same results. Actually, some optimizers (like Oracle's) will try to convert the first solution into the second one in real time. That's called an OR-expansion.